# How to disable preflight cache-control headers for Angular service-worker (when calling event stream)?

Tags: angular, service-worker, server-sent-events, preflight, http-status-code-504

**Update 2: See my answer below. The 504 error is fixed**

UPDATE: It appears this is NOT due to the `cache-control` headers, despite the error. If I disable the service worker, the headers are still present. Instead, this is due to the service worker causing `504 (Gateway Timeout)` on the API. Any idea how to fix this?

I've built a full MEAN-stack app and it works great until I use service workers.

The main error I get is

`Failed to load ${apiUrl} Request header field Cache-Control is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response.`

I get this when trying to access an external API (api.particle.io), where I have no control over their CORS settings.

I've tried adjusting my `ngsw-config.json` by adding the API url to `dataGroups`, but so far, that just adds an additional error:

`Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Failed to fetch        ngsw-worker.js`

This only happens when trying to fetch an event stream using:

```
watchStatus(url: string): Observable<eventResponse> {
        return new Observable<eventResponse>(obs => {
            const source = new EventSource(url);
            source.addEventListener('status', (event) => {
                obs.next(JSON.parse(event.data).data);
            });
            return () => source.close();
        });
    }
```

**Is there a way to call this with an observable?** I couldn't get Server-Sent Events working without `EventSource`, but maybe I'm doing it wrong.

My `ngsw-config.json`:

```
{
  "index": "/index.html",
  "assetGroups": [{
    "name": "app",
    "installMode": "prefetch",
    "resources": {
      "files": [
        "/favicon.ico",
        "/index.html",
        "/*.css",
        "/*.js"
      ]
    }
  }, {
    "name": "assets",
    "installMode": "lazy",
    "updateMode": "prefetch",
    "resources": {
      "files": [
        "/assets/**"
      ]
    }
  }, {
    "name": "fonts",
    "resources": {
      "urls": [
        "https://fonts.googleapis.com/**",
        "https://fonts.gstatic.com/**"
      ]
    }
}],
  "dataGroups": [
      {
          "name": "photon-api",
          "urls": [
              "http://api.particle.io/**",
              "https://api.particle.io/**"
          ],
          "cacheConfig" : {
              "strategy": "freshness",
              "maxSize": 0,
              "maxAge": "0u"
          }
      }
  ]
}
```

<strike>Is it possible to disable the preflight `Cache-Control` header changing my `ngsw-config.json`?</strike>

Answer (score 5):

Got it!

I fixed it based off [a github issue answer found here](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/24716#issuecomment-402233362).

Basically, the service worker catches *everything* with `onFetch`. To whitelist my API URLs, I opened `ngsw-worker.js` and changed `onFetch(event)` to:

```
onFetch(event) {
    const req = event.request;
    // List of words in request URL to whitelist/bypass the service worker
    const whitelist = ['api', 'otherWhitelistWords...']
    // Check to see if request url contains any whitelisted words and skip the rest of onFetch if it does
    if (whitelist.some(word => req.url.toLowerCase().includes(word.toLowerCase()))) {
                return
    }
   ...
}
```

You can automate fixing of `ng build:prod` by creating a `fix-sw.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash
sed -i "/onFetch(event) {/,/const req = event.request;/c onFetch(event){const req=event.request;const whitelist=['api','otherWhitelistWords...'];if(whitelist.some(word=>req.url.toLowerCase().includes(word.toLowerCase()))){return}" ./dist/${PROJECTNAME}/ngsw-worker.js
```

then, in `package.json`, change your `build:prod` to:

```
"build:prod": "ng build --prod && bash ./fix-sw.sh",
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Angular 6? if yes, CLI 6 support proxy-config which will proxy your backend API. Please check whether this helps.

https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/blob/master/docs/documentation/stories/proxy.md

Comment: I am using v6. Unfortunately, the proxy support is only for `ng serve` and not `ng build`, which is where the service worker is used.

Comment: You can create a proxy web server (i.e middleware) which can communicate the external API. Your mobile app can hit the middle ware and it will return the response from the external api